# Postgres bulk update on rows using multi-column subqueries

Tags: postgresql, subquery, rollup, multiple-columns

I need to update all the rows in a table(parent table) with summary values (count, min, max) from child tables on 6 fields on the parent table

```
tab1 (parent table)
-------------------
tab1_ID 
tab1_low
tab1_high
tab2_ref_count
tab2_ref_low
tab2_ref_high
tab3_ref_count
tab3_ref_low
tab3_ref_high
STUS_CD

tab2 (link table for tab1 to tab1)
----------------------------------
tab1_ID
tab1_ref_ID

tab3 (link table for tab1 to tab4)
----------------------------------
tab1_ID
tab4_ref_ID

tab4
-----
tab4_ID
tab4_low
tab4_high
```

To roll up counts of tab2 and tab3 into tab1, below is the query I am attempting -

```
UPDATE tab1
SET    (tab2_ref_count, tab2_ref_low, tab2_ref_high)  = 
                     (SELECT COUNT(t1.tab1_ID), MIN(t1.tab1_low),     MAX(t1.tab1_high)
                      FROM   tab2 t2 JOIN tab1 t1 ON (t2.tab1_ref_ID =     t1.tab1_ID) 
                      WHERE  tab1.tab1_ID = t2.tab1_ID),
       (tab3_ref_count, tab3_ref_low, tab3_ref_high)  = 
                     (SELECT COUNT(t4.tab4_ID), MIN(t4.tab4_low),       MAX(t4.tab4_high)
                      FROM   tab3 t3 JOIN tab4 t4 ON (t3.tab4_ref_ID =     t4.tab4_ID)
                      WHERE  tab1.tab1_ID = t3.tab1_ID)
WHERE  STUS_CD IN ('01','02')
```

But apparently it's not working. Any tips please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could work like this:

```
UPDATE tab1 t1
SET    tab2_ref_count = t2.ct
     , tab2_ref_low   = t2.low
     , tab2_ref_high  = t2.high
     , tab3_ref_count = t3.ct
     , tab3_ref_low   = t3.low
     , tab3_ref_high  = t3.high
FROM  (
    SELECT t2.tab1_id
         , count(*)          AS ct
         , min(t1.tab1_low)  AS low
         , max(t1.tab1_high) AS high
    FROM  tab2 t2
    JOIN  tab1 t1 ON t1.tab1_id = t2.tab1_ref_id 
    GROUP BY 1
    ) t2
JOIN  (
    SELECT t3.tab1_id
         , count(*)          AS ct
         , min(t4.tab1_low)  AS low
         , max(t4.tab1_high) AS high
    FROM   tab3 t3
    JOIN   tab4 t4 ON t4.tab4_id = t3.tab4_ref_id 
    GROUP  BY 1
    ) t3 USING (tab1_id)
WHERE  stus_cd IN ('01','02')
AND    t1.tab1_id = t2.tab1_id;
-- AND    t1.tab1_id = COALESCE(t2.tab1_id, t3.tab1_id);  .. for FULL OUTER JOIN
```

#### Major points:

- I use `count(*)` instead of `count(t4.tab1_id)`. Same result guaranteed here, but simpler, faster.
- The query assumes that there are rows in `tab3` for every `tab1_id` that is in `tab2`, too. If that is not the case, you have to change the `JOIN` type to `LEFT JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Use the provided alternative in the final WHERE clause in this case.
- This query will not update rows in `tab1` at all, if not related rows are found in either `tab2` or `tab3`.

Comment: Thanks Erwin and a_horse.... Erwin, on your second assumption, there is no relationship between the tab1_ID in tab2 and tab3. Could that explain why the UPDATE only affects records that have rows in tab3 and tab2 even when I use a FULL OUTER JOIN ? How can I get around this ? Also, with the introduction of a 3rd link table tab5 and a tab6(corresponding detail table) to the UPDATE statement, do you think performance will suffer? Is it better to run 3 separate UPDATES instead? What are your thoughts ?

Comment: @user558122: If you use `FULL OUTER JOIN`, then my disclaimer does not apply. It's meant for my current version with `JOIN`. As to your second question see my amended answer. Of course, you can always spit into two updates. Would be easier to understand, but slower, because rows will be updated repeatedly. If you can wrap your head around this solution: should be the optimum.

Comment: Thanks Erwin again. For some reason, even with the amended query (FULL OUTER JOIN), the query is still not updating exclusive cases. It only updates where there are rows in both tab2 and tab3.

Comment: @user558122: That should not be. I rechecked. Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere? It's a complex query, can easily happen. Or maybe you have entries in `t2` / `t3` but no matching entries in `t4`?

Comment: I just corrected my original post. I noticed a typo. First Link table is a self-linking table (tab1 to tab1). What I noticed was that there were records in t2 that had matching records in t1 but not in t3. For those records, their aggregate values were not updated in t1.

Comment: @user558122: I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. I still can't get it to handle exceptions in either table tab2 or tab3. It forces a JOIN on them. I'll probably split the UPDATEs for now. I really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: @user558122: I found a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not support tuple definitions in an update statement (I think it's planned though)

You can use something like this (not tested):

```
UPDATE tab1
  SET tab2_ref_count = tt1.tab1_id_count, 
      tab2_ref_low = tt1.tab1_low_min, 
      tab2_ref_high = tt1.tab1_high_max
FROM (
     SELECT COUNT(t1.tab1_ID) as tab1_id_count, 
            MIN(t1.tab1_low) as tab1_low_min,     
            MAX(t1.tab1_high) as tab1_high_max
     FROM  tab2 t2 
     JOIN tab1 t1 ON (t2.tab1_ref_ID = t1.tab1_ID) 
     WHERE  tab1.tab1_ID = t2.tab1_ID
 ) tt1
 ....
 WHERE  STUS_CD IN ('01','02')
```

(where `...` indicates a second derived table for the second sub-select in your example)